# how to debug why layer navigation getItemsCount() return zero?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, product-attribute, layered-navigation

In layer navigation multiselect attribute not displayed.
`$filter->getItemsCount()` in `vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml` always return zero.

```
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
        <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
    <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
        <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
            <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
            <dd class="filter-options-content"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**My try**

`$filter` have all the **multiselect** attribute but `$filter->getItemsCount()` return zero.

e.g)

`$filter` have `brand` attribute, category page have many products which have **brand** value however `$filter->getItemsCount()` return **zero**

please suggest nicer way to debug?

**Note:** I did reindex. All cahce are disabled. In admin, we enabled needed properties to display in Navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file:-

> vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php

There you can check `public function apply`

That can help you out in debugging. Another way of debugging is to use Xdebug. It is a good way of seeing how files are being used.

More info can be seen here:-

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/docker/docker-development-debug.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll suggest a few things with an answer.

Make sure the attribute in question is set to `"filterable (with results)"` or `"filterable (no results)"` in `Use in Layered Navigation`.

You might have mistakenly selected this option: `Use in Search Results Layered Navigation`

If all of your products have the same brand the brand filter won't show if `filterable (with results)` is selected.

So you might want to change this to `filterable (no results)` for testing purposes.

I would also recommend disabling 3rd party modules that might have changed the functionality of Layered navigation and check if that helps.